# Can regular bike forks be modified to allow front drivetrain setup?

Tags: front, modification, alternative-drivetrain

Can regular bike forks be modified to allow front drivetrain setup?

Some bikes have front drivetrains instead rear drivetrains. The problem is that bike stores don't seem to carry forks that have a derailleur hanger. Forks don't always outlast the bike and custom building another fork is likely very expensive unless it's mass produced.

It's possible that you want or need a different style of fork. One might prefer metal instead of carbon fiber for safety and a larger room for errors, one might need a different style for panniers and fenders for touring and commuting purposes, one might need a different shape for fork lights or cameras, one might prefer mounting holes for a disc brake caliper, you nane it.

Here are some bikes that have a front drivetrain:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can you widen a steel fork from 100mm to 130mm to accommodate 8 through 10 speed hubs using the cold set method? 30mm of widening sounds quite large. It's almost three sizes up. I've heard of 10mm. What are the risks? Once you widen it, how do you install the derailleur? Can you tap a custom shaped steel bar and use it as a derailleur hanger?

You can find standard spacings for hubs and seatstays here:
https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html

Comment: Note that these bikes are either recumbent bikes and/or have hand-driven front wheels. Which of these is your goal?

Comment: I would make one using carbon fibre (foam core, wrap fibers around core, wet with epoxy resin, wrap with heat-shrink foil, shrink). I think a fork could be a decent first carbon-fibre-composite-project.

Comment: The Twicycle is my dream bike.

Answer (score 6):

To cold set a regular fork by 30+ mm would no doubt weaken it far too much to use. The better starting point would be something like a 135 mm fat bike fork, common sizes are also listed in the Sheldon brown table you linked.

Notice however, that three of the four pictures you found feature extensive modifications to strengthen the fork or supporting frame to handle the pedalling forces. None of them will have off the shelf forks, they will all be custom made, along with the whole frame; they have totally different riding positions to a regular bicycle.

If you are serious about getting a bike with front wheel drive, it’s worth doing properly which would mean sourcing something specially designed for the purpose.

Comment: Note how heavy the fork is on that TwiCycle - that's no off-the-shelf, stock fork.  Also, that crankset on the handlebars is set perfectly to slice your face and/or neck right in half...

Comment: @Andrew yes there is a lot wrong with that one - I didn’t want to entertain it any further

Comment: @AndrewHenle And the brake cables will wind around the handlebars and chain and... It's clearly not an actual bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Are you sure?  https://twicycle.com/

Comment: @AndrewHenle Now I'm seriously confused. How can the brake cables _not_ wrap themselves around the handebars?

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Pure magic?  Maybe set up a GoFundMe so someone can try to buy one and find out?  :-)

Comment: @David The same way as the other hand cycle, the handles articulate

Comment: Having been a bit down on that TwiCycle, the longer video on the website shows it in a better light, it almost looks fun

Comment: Heavy fork? Isn't the Twicycle's fork carbon fiber?

Comment: @Han-Lin yes it's carbon, I think he means heavy construction, as opposed to a slim racing fork and therefore specially selected for the task. it will be heavier than normal, but light for its size.

Comment: Since it's front driven it would make sense to make it stronger. It would have additional stresses.

Comment: For the Twicycle, it has a chest pad not shown in the picture which prevents getting cut. Our max power from our arms can be over 400W. E bikes might need heavy duty forks too. You can google carbon e-bikes. If I get it, I plan to use it for fitness so I think it's a good invention. Rowers have fairly muscular upper bodies. I think pedalling it for 30 minutes a day produce different forms of adaptations compared to weight lifting 50 reps 2/3x a week.